# iOS - load UIWebView content synchronously?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a UITableView with many rows, each row contains a UIWebView. The content of this webView is stored in my database (on the app), and the height of each cell in tableView is calculated based on the scroll height of my UIWebView.

Here is the problem, the `loadHtmlString` method works asynchronously so when `heighForRowAtIndexPath` method of UITableView get's called, the data hasn't been loaded in the UIWebView (because it works asynchronously). So I cannot calculate the required height for the cell.

So here is the question, is it possible to load the content of a UIWebView synchronously? my html text is very short, so it shouldn't take that long to load it synchronously.

**EDIT:**
Is it possible to calculate the expected height of an html string without placing it inside a UIWebView, I know that this is possible using plain text, I don't know about html

Comment: Can you pre-calculate the height and include that in the database?

Comment: As a last-resort hack you could block the thread until it's loaded by using a global flag.

Comment: @MattH Yes I thought about it, but I rather not store UI information in my database.

Comment: How about a Call back into the ObjC app from a $(document).ready() function, basically tell it to go ahead and calc the height?

Comment: @MattH a callback doesn't work because it might return after the height of the cell has been asked already

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could:

1) Return the default height at the first heighForRowAtIndexPath call

2) Load your HTML

3) Wait for the event webViewDidFinishLoad and store in an array the final height

```
  - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

4) Update the cell height by calling

```
  [self.tableView beginUpdates];
  [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:YES];
  [self.tableView endUpdates];
```

5) Return the final height when heighForRowAtIndexPath is called

Comment: +1, but you will get some interesting autosizing issues if the `UIWebView`s have `scalesPageToFit` enabled.

Comment: I have tried this , the problem is when you scroll fast through a bunch of cells.

Comment: aryaxt, what is the result when you scroll fast?

Comment: I see lot's of weird resizing, because it's reusing cells. And the cell its using could have an unexpected height, and as soon as the webView calls back then it animates to the correct size.

Comment: I'll mark this as best answer because it's the closest to what I was trying to get done. I ended up creating custom UIViews and store them in an array, and then insert them into UITableViewCells as needed. This is probably not the best way of solving this problem when it comes to performance, but it's the best solution that worked in this situation.

Comment: remember to set uiwebview delegate to nil to avoid weird behaviour

Answer (score 0):

If the html you have is short, why not put some inline `CSS` into it which explicitly sets the `height` parameter of the document `body`, and then parse that value before you load it into the `UIWebView`?

Comment: You didn't specify that it was dynamic. For all I know you were just storing HTML formatted text to preserve colours etc. I didn't say it was the best solution, but it's a quick solution for short, static HTML code.